# DocumentClient.CreateDocumentQuery throws a "not an instance" error when running a query

Tags: c#, azure, exception, azure-cosmosdb, documentclient

I'm writing a .NET web service that takes documents from a cosmosDB database. I writing a function in another project (that is supposed to be as generic as possible) to retrieve a document, so that the WS will use it.

I'm using `DocumentClients` function `CreateDocumentQuery` like this:

```
public static async Task<T1> GetMyDocumentAsync<T1>(eDataBase databaseName, eCollection collectionName, eFields key, string val)
{
    var option = new FeedOptions { EnableCrossPartitionQuery = true };
    Uri uri = UriFactory.CreateDocumentCollectionUri(databaseName.ToString(), collectionName.ToString());
    IQueryable<T1> res = Client.CreateDocumentQuery<T1>(uri, option);
    document = res.AsEnumerable<T1>().FirstOrDefault();
}
```

This works fine, returning the first document in the database. But changing the usage of `CreateDocumentQuery` to this:

```
IQueryable<T1> res = Client.CreateDocumentQuery<T1>(uri, "SELECT * FROM c",option);
```

And wrapped inside a try-catch block throws an exception that has an `InnerException` that states:

> Object not set to an instance of an object.

Also some of the exception fields are:

```
Data = {System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal}
```

and

```
Error = {{ "code": "BadRequest",
           "message": "\r\nActivityId: SOMEGUID" }}
```

The query works on that collection from the azure portal.

The client properties I'm using are:

ConnectionMode = **Gateway** and Protocol = **Https**.

Any ideas as to why this usage works and the other using an explicit query string won't? I also tried using a `SqlQuerySpec` object and the result was the same. I don't want to use the `Where()` function since I want to use generic types. The async keyword was meant for future use.

Comment: Well clearly the issue is the NRE that you are getting. You need to debug to see which object is null in there. On top of that it's worth saying that the way you wrote the quest, you are actually getting the full collection before only picking the first item so you will have performance issues. On a side note, it might be a good idea to take a look at [Cosmonaut](https://github.com/Elfocrash/Cosmonaut) as it looks like it can do everything you are trying to code.

Comment: @NickChapsas Thanks for bringing Cosmonaut up, We will consider testing it. For now I am interested in using Microsoft's `DocumentClient` class. I have tried debugging it for nulls for some time but I did not find anything useful. The null reference happens when I try to take the first element, or convert to a list, or just enumerate the enumerable. But again when I do the same thing with no query argument the enumeration works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I solved it.

When creating the collection I tried to query in the question, I noticed that a partition key is mandatory. All my other collections up in cosmos did not have any. So I figured that some of the settings should be different for collections that do have partition keys.

The part that throw the null exception was enumerating the document query. The function usage looked OK according to the documentation so I thought that the problem was with the `CreateDocumentQuery`. That is because it created a "faulty" object, with some null fields and it might be due to the change in collection partition keys.

So I tried updating the package Microsoft.Azure.DocumentDB for my entire solution to the lastest stable version (2.2.0 at the time being) and then it just worked.